# estimate a integral with parameter

Tags: calculus, integration, lebesgue-integral

Consider the following integral:
$$J(u)=\int_{0}^{u^2}\int_{0}^{u}\frac{1}{x^3+y+3x^2+5x+3}dxdy$$
**My question:** I want to separate it into two parts:
$$J(u)=u^aI(u)$$
where $a\geq 0$ and $I(u)$ is "smaller" than polynomials, that is, $I(u)$ satisfies the followings:

(1) $\liminf\limits_{u\rightarrow+\infty}I(u)>0$.
(2) for any $p>0$, $\lim\limits_{u\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{I(u)}{u^p}=0$

*For example, $I(u)=\log(u)$, or $\arctan u$ etc.*

**My attempt:** I first guess $a=0$, that is, $J(u)$ itself satisfies $I(u)$. But I can't show that property (2) above. Then I guess $a=1$, that is, $J(u)=uI(u)$, I can show that property (2) by change the variables $(\frac{x}{u},\frac{y}{u^2})=(w,s)$ and using Dominated convergence theorem. But this case I can't show the property (1)... And now I use computer to calculate, I guess $a$ may be between $(0,1)$.

**Some tips**:

(i) if you change the variables, $(\frac{x}{u},\frac{y}{u^2})=(w,s)$ may be better. this is called dilation and it is a kind of "homogeneous"

(ii) If I change $x^3$ into $xy$ in $J(u)$, I can show that actually $a=0$, by Dominated convergence theorem.

**Background**: Given a dilation in $R^n$:
$$D_t(x)=(t^{c_1}x_1,...,t^{c_n}x_n)$$
then consider
$P(x,r)=r^nf_n(x)+...+r^Qf_Q(x)$,
where $Q=m_1+...+m_n$, $f_k(x)$ satisfies $f_k(D_t(x))=t^{Q-k}f_k(x)$, and $f(x)>0$ are the combinations of positive monomials ($x_i>0$).
The origin type of the denominator of the $J(u)$ is $x^3r^3+(y+3x^2)r^4+5xr^5+3r^6$. And the dilation is $D_t(x)=(t^{1}x,t^2y,t^{3}z)$. I just take $1/r=u$ and do some simplification.

Comment: One direct simplification is to change the order of integration, to get
$$
\begin{split}
J(u)
 &= \int_0^{u^2}\int_0^u\frac{dxdy}{x^3+y+3x^2+5x+3} \\
 &= \int_0^u \left[
         \int_0^{u^2}\frac{dy}{x^3+y+3x^2+5x+3} \right] dx \\
 &= \int_0^u \ln \left(\frac{x^3+3x^2+5x+3}
                            {u^2+x^3+3x^2+5x+3} \right) dx \\
 &= \int_0^u \ln \left(1 - \frac{u^2}
                            {u^2+x^3+3x^2+5x+3} \right) dx \\
\end{split}
$$

Comment: but, maybe you calculate wrong? the integral should be positive but yours is nagetive... and if you calculate in the right way you will find that's not a good way to due with the integral

Comment: We have
$$J(u) = \int_0^u \ln \left( 1 + \frac {u^2} {P(x)} \right) dx, \\
J'(u) = 2 u \int_0^u \frac {dx} {P(x) + u^2} +
 \ln \left( 1 + \frac {u^2} {P(u)} \right).$$
The integral in $J'(u)$ (which is similar to [this integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3718462)) can be brute-forced by writing out an antiderivative in terms of a sum over the roots of $P(x) + u^2$ and taking an asymptotic expansion of the roots for large $u$. This gives
$$J'(u) \sim \frac {4 \pi} {3 \sqrt 3 \hspace {1.5px} u^{1/3}},$$
therefore
$$J(u) \sim \frac {2 \pi u^{2/3}} {\sqrt 3}$$
by l'Hopital's rule.

Comment: @Maxim Good idea by l'Hopital's rule! By the way, do you have any reference to due with such integrals? This is just a concrete example. The more general type is like the description in the "background" in the body above.($P(x,r)=....$)